# Multiple websites running in docker containers, how to implement?

Tags: nginx, docker, virtualhost

I am running two docker containers, using the following docker-composer script:

```
db:
  image: cofoundry/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
    - MYSQL_PASS=wordpress
    - MYSQL_DB=wordpress
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  privileged: true

web:
  image: cofoundry/nginx-phpfpm
  volumes:
    - ../bedrock:/app
  environment:
    - DOCROOT=/app/web
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  privileged: true
```

But I'm not sure how can I go about running multiple nginx-phpfpm web containers with different sites, like web_1, web_2 etc. ?

Or, alternatively, how to propagate custom nginx.conf while running docker-composer up, so I can configure virtualhosts there.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: Look into [autodock](https://github.com/prologic/autodock) -- It lets you setup a way to manage multiple website(s) by simply pointing a wildcard dns entry at your Docker host. See: [A Docker-based mini PaaS](http://shortcircuit.net.au/~prologic/blog/article/2015/03/24/a-docker-based-mini-paas/)

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do it (*as I mentioend in my comment*) is to use something like [autodock](https://github.com/prologic/autodock):

**Example:** (*based on your `docker-compose.yml`*):

```
db:
  image: cofoundry/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
    - MYSQL_PASS=wordpress
    - MYSQL_DB=wordpress
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  privileged: true

web:
  image: cofoundry/nginx-phpfpm
  volumes:
    - ../bedrock:/app
  environment:
    - DOCROOT=/app/web
    - VIRTUALHOST=myapp.example.com
  links:
    - db
  privileged: true

autodock:
    image: prologic/autodock
    ports:
        - "1338:1338/udp"
        - "1338:1338/tcp"
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

autodockhipache:
    image: prologic/autodock-hipache
    links:
        - autodock
        - hipache:redis

hipache:
    image: hipache
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
```

The only **requirement** is that you setup a wildcard DNS entry for `*.example.com` to point to your "Docker Host". e.g:

```
*.example.com A 1.1.1.1
```

You can read more about how this all works in the article:

[A Docker-based mini PaaS](http://shortcircuit.net.au/~prologic/blog/article/2015/03/24/a-docker-based-mini-paas/)

This will scale and work for as many websites as you want to run on your "Docker Host".

**Edit:** The nice thing about this setup is that it's simple, it's automated and it only requires you add a single extra environment variable to the container you want to expose to the web with only one initial setup requirements (*wildcard dns entry*).